# jQuery parseHTML - Getting and Setting Values

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to use jQuery to read/parse a selection of valid HTML such that you can use jQuery methods on it such as .val() or .html()?

The below is not working for me. I have tried .html() and .val().

```
html = $.parseHTML('<div id="one">blah</div><div id="two">blurp</div>');
console.log ($(html).find('#one').text());
```

Comment: Check [`html = $('<div id="one">blah</div><div id="two">blurp</div>').filter('#one').text();
alert(html);`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8w8vqbvy/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to use `parseHTML` on HTML string.

Wrap it in jQuery object and use methods on it.

```js
var html = $('<div id="one">blah</div><div id="two">blurp</div>').filter('#one').html();
document.write(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Quick question.  How to you write to the element?  For example i need to change the value 'blah' in the DIV with id"one" to read "BLAHBLAH"

Comment: `var $html = $('<div id="one">blah</div><div id="two">blurp</div>').filter('#one').html('Blah Blah');` and then to get updated html use `$html[0]`